# How to get inverting amp in an electronics project with 1 battery

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I am trying to invert the signal from a microphone for a simple noise cancellation project.  I am using a 3.7V lipo battery, right now I am trying to use a single supply op amp (TLV2462), but don't know how to get the negative signal out.  I don't need much power/voltage out, I can boost power with a second stage, I'm mostly just concerned with getting a good inverted signal with 1 battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op amps need a dual supply to operate. If you are working from a single supply, you can create an "artificial ground" like this:

[image: inverting single supply op amp]

You can then use this mid-rail "ground" (which draws very little DC current but has a low impedance to the real power rails because of the capacitor) to bias your opamp (the + input) and also to reference your input signal. Because of this there is a DC block capacitor at the input.

You don't say what kind of mic you use - if it is a dynamic type they like to see an impedance of about 2k, hence the 2k2 input resistor. The gain can be set with the feedback resistor - here we have 22k which gives 20dB. A small cap across that resistor would also be a good idea for stability.

(Note that if you are using an electret mic, this won't work - they need a power supply of a few volts. Also, with this circuit, you will get a nasty "pop" at power up because charge current flows through the mic - not great for it. It might be better to move the mic ground connection to "fake ground" - but that depends on how other things are grounded too. Experiment.)

(If you have a spare opamp section, you can use it as a unity gain buffer to improve your "virtual ground". There is also an IC made for the purpose, the TLE2426, which does a good  job.)

Comment: https://imgur.com/UOr8GsP                                                 Thank you for this help!  I got my basic circuit working.  I am using a TLV4112 since I want to get more output than most op-amps drive.  The microphone/preamp that I have designated in this photo as just a signal source outputs the signal on vcc/2 so I don't have a DC blocking cap there.  Do you think I should still work in the TLE2426 or similar IC?

Comment: you're welcome. The TLE2426 is a reliable way to generate the mid-rail reference, and doesn't cost much, so it is a good solution. But using two resistors also works (note that it is also advised to add a bypass cap of about 10uF or so from the midrail point to the true ground, which is the negative supply to the opamp - you have not put that in your circuit).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a negative power supply to invert an audio signal.  Use DC blocking capacitors on the input and output and bias the input to VCC/2.  The value of R1 and R2 will set the gain, the value of C3 depends on the impedance of the load.

This works by shifting the average level of the input signal to half way between 0V and VCC, inverting it, then shifting the average level of the output back to 0V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiO6hI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I believe this circuit does not have negative feedback. Also, if you swap + and -, you will get a non-inverting amplifier while Brady was trying to invert it for a simple noise-cancelling application. The explanation is correct though, maybe just update the schematic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure as well that R2 and R1 need to be moved over to the inverting input.  Can the non-invert input just be tied to ground?

Comment: Sorry about that, schematic corrected.

Comment: Isn't that a non-inverting amplifier?

Comment: Yes, it was, corrected.

Comment: If this is a single  supply circuit, I don't see how this can work. The negative rail is GND. The positive input is connected to the negative rail.

Comment: Consider where the average value for the audio signal is.  On the input it can be centered around 0V.  C1 blocks the DC component of that signal and R4/R5/C4 bias the other side of the capacitor to half way between 0V and VCC (no assuming the peak to peak voltage is less than VCC the signal does not extend down below 0V any more).  It is then inverted (possibly with gain) and C3 allows the center value of the output to float.  It you drive a ground referenced load it will restore the middle value of the signal to 0V restoring the negative voltage swings.

Comment: I see that. But you do not show power connections to the opamp. What are your power pins connected to?

Comment: The opamp is powered from the battery (in reality with a bypass cap near the opamp), no negative voltages are required..  If you use the online simulator you will see there are no negative voltages on the inputs or outputs of the opamp.  BTW, google ltspice for a good, free simulation program you can use offline to experiment with circuits like this virtually.

Comment: Dean, Can I increase R1, R2, R4, and R5 so less current goes through them?  I am going to be powering this mobile application through a small 1s lipo battery and want as long as life as possible.    Also, what is a good online simulation program?  I haven't been able to figure any of them out yet.  I have LT spice, and am still working on getting it to simulate anything other than DC .op point.

Comment: R1,R2 and R3 won't affect the power consumption significantly.  You can increase R4 and R5, but pretty soon you are going to need to use a second opamp to buffer the output of the voltage divider.  Using a dual opamp and a buffer is a typical solution for a high quality, lower power design.